# Drawing a border around a custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, android-custom-view

here is a quick description of my screen layout.

```
<CustomLayout>
    <CardView>
        <CustomTextView />
        <CustomTextView />
        <CustomTextView />
    </CardView>
    <CustomTextView />
    <CustomTextView />
</CustomLayout>
```

I coded it so that `CardView extends LinearLayout` and `CustomTextView extends TextView`. Everything works fine except I want to draw a border line at the bottom of the `CardView` and at the bottom of the second `CustomTextView`. To do so, I use the same method for my `CardView` and my `CustomTextView`:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    getLocalVisibleRect(mRect);
    if (mDrawBottomBorder)
        canvas.drawLine(mRect.left, mRect.bottom, mRect.right, mRect.bottom, mBorderPaint);
}
```

That method gets called in both cases, i.e. for my `CardView` and `CustomTextView` but it doesn't draw the border for my `CardView`! I suspect it's because it `extends LinearLayout` and not `TextView` but shouldn't it work anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. My 3rd `CustomTextView` in my `CardView` layout was covering the border beneath it so the line wasn't visible.